# S3 upload is slower in other region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have configured the bucket in US region.

I suppose due to that the file upload from sydney region seems to be lot slower.

Any suggestions to improve the upload speed?

Comment: Have you considered [S3 Accelerator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html). It uses CloudFront's edge location to upload faster.

Comment: Are the majority of the users of this bucket actually in the US? What is the general architecture of your application?